# sum case when in grails gorm

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I need build a gorm query returning a status field sum case when

like this `sum(case when status = 0 then 1 else 0 end) waiting_data`

my gorm query is :

```
return Product.createCriteria().list() {
            resultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
            projections {
                count("id")
                property("so.id", "id")
                property("so.soNumber", "soNumber")
                property("so.dateCreated", "dateCreated")
                property("acc.name", "account_name")
                property("proj.name", "project_name")
                property("gtin", "gtin")
                property("status", "status")
                property("statusDate", "status_date")

                sqlRestriction ("sum(case when status = 0 then 1 else 0 end) waiting_data")

                groupProperty("so.id")
                groupProperty("so.soNumber")
                groupProperty("so.dateCreated")
                groupProperty("acc.name")
                groupProperty("proj.name")
                groupProperty("proj.name")
                groupProperty("gtin")
                groupProperty("status")
                groupProperty("statusDate")

            }
```

Is possible use sum(case when ...) in grails gorm projections??

how do this?

Comment: You can definitely use it in Product.executeQuery("...arbitrary HQL...") but I don't know if it's allowed in a projection or not.  Whether a straight query is an option for you probably depends on your specific use case.

Comment: Well is it? Assuming you are asking it does not work for you?  What are the errors?

Comment: @cfrick i Try "sqlRestriction ("sum(case when status = 0 then 1 else 0 end) waiting_data")" but this didn´t work

Comment: Are you allowed to use hql?